# Minimalist Form not Validating

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, email

I'm trying to update a previously created form to use new fields. At the moment only the email is validating, if you click send it only shows that the email field is empty (turns the border red).

jsFiddle of the code is located **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/DJdTB/3/)**.

I assume I'm overlooking a glaringly obvious mistake.

HTML:

```
                <div class="success"> Contact form submitted!<br> <strong>We will be in touch soon.</strong></div>
                <form id="form-1" class="form-1" name="form-1" method="post" action="index.html" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input class="inputbox" name="name" id="name" type="text" value="Your Name:" onFocus="if(this.value=='Your Name:'){this.value=''}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Your Name:'}" />
                    <input class="inputbox top-2" name="email" id="email" type="text" value="E-mail:" onFocus="if(this.value=='E-mail:'){this.value=''}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='E-mail:'}" />
                    <input class="inputbox top-2" name="phone" id="phone" type="text" value="Phone:" onFocus="if(this.value=='Phone:'){this.value=''}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Phone:'}" />
                    <div class="select-3 top-2 fleft">
                        <select name="select" name="adults" id="adults" >
                            <option selected disabled>Adults</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="9+">9+</option>
                        </select>   
                    </div>
                    <div class="select-3 top-2  fleft">
                        <select name="select" name="children" id="children" >
                            <option selected disabled>Children</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="9+">9+</option>
                        </select>   
                    </div> 
                    <div class="select-3 top-2 fleft last-1">
                        <select name="select" name="rooms" id="rooms" >
                            <option selected disabled>Rooms</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="9+">9+</option>
                        </select>   
                    </div> 
                    <div class="select-2 top-2 fleft">
                        <input class="inputbox_date" name="checkin" id="checkin" value="Check-In Date:" onFocus="if(this.value=='Check-In Date:'){this.value=''}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Check-In Date:'}" /> 
                        <input class="inputbox_date" name="checkout" id="checkout" value="Check-Out Date:" onFocus="if(this.value=='Check-Out Date:'){this.value=''}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Check-Out Date:'}" />  
                    </div> 
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="height-3 border-2 pad-2">
                        <textarea class="textarea top-2" name="comments" id="comments" onFocus="if(this.value=='ADDITIONAL COMMENTS:'){this.value=''}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='ADDITIONAL COMMENTS:'}">ADDITIONAL COMMENTS:</textarea>
                    </div>
                    <p class="center"><a href="javascript:void(0);" name="submitlink" id="submitlink" class="button top-1">Send</a></p>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </form>
```

JS:

```
function checkValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-+\s]+")|([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*)|("[\w-+\s]+")([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*))(@((?:[\w-+]+\.)*\w[\w-+]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][\d]\.|1[\d]{2}\.|[\d]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][\d]|1[\d]{2}|[\d]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][\d]|1[\d]{2}|[\d]{1,2})\]?$)/i);

    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};

var mailsendstatus;
function userSendMailStatus(uname, uemail, uphone, uadults, uchildren, urooms, ucheckin, ucheckout, umsg) {
    // checking for some valid user name
    if(!uname) {
        $("#name").addClass('formError');
    }
    else if (uname){
        $("#name").removeClass('formError');    
    }

    // checking for valid email
    if(!checkValidEmailAddress(uemail)) {
        $("#email").addClass('formError');
    }
    else if(checkValidEmailAddress(uemail)) {
        $("#email").removeClass('formError');   
    }

    // checking for phone
    if(!uphone) {
        $("#phone").addClass('formError');
    }
    else if (uphone) {
        $("#phone").removeClass('formError');   
    }

    // checking for checkin
    if(!ucheckin){
        $("#checkin").addClass('formError');
    }
    else if(ucheckin){
        $("#checkin").removeClass('formError'); 
    }

    // checking for checkout
    if(!ucheckout) {
        $("#checkout").addClass('formError');
    }
    else if(!ucheckout){
        $("#checkout").removeClass('formError');    
    }


    if(uname && checkValidEmailAddress(uemail) && uphone && ucheckin && ucheckout) {
        // in this case all of our inputs look good
        // so we say true and send the mail
        mailsendstatus = true;

        $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'js/sendmail.php',
                data: $("#form-1").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data == "yes") {
                    $(".success").toggle();
                    $("#form-1").slideUp(650);
                    }
                }
            }
    )};

    return mailsendstatus;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form-1").submit(function() { return false; });

    $("#submitlink").bind("click", function(e){
        var subnamevalue  = $("#name").val();
        var emailvalue    = $("#email").val();
        var phonevalue    = $("#phone").val();
        var adultsvalue   = $("#adults").val();
        var childrenvalue = $("#children").val();
        var roomsvalue    = $("#rooms").val();
        var checkinvalue  = $("#checkin").val();
        var checkoutvalue = $("#checkout").val();
        var msgvalue      = $("#comments").val();


        var postchecks = userSendMailStatus(subnamevalue, emailvalue, phonevalue, adultsvalue, childrenvalue, roomsvalue, checkinvalue, checkoutvalue, msgvalue);
    });
});
```

Comment: When your function runs to check if they are empty it sees your place holder text.  None of the fields are in fact empty/blank.  The email works because you also check if it is a valid email address.

Comment: And that's why I needed fresh eyes on this! Heh. Feel free to use that as an Answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your function runs to check if they are empty it sees your place holder text. None of the fields are in fact empty/blank. The email works because you also check if it is a valid email address.